# search on outlook item by UserProperties

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I have to save my database pkid to outlook. I used `UserProperties["TaskId"]`. I have tried to find the item by this id, and the below code is not working

```
tasksFolder.Items.Find(string.Format("[TaskId] = '{0}'", id))
```

Is there anyway to find my items instead of looping on all my lists!
Is there any better way to save Database id on outlook, EntryID is readonly.

Comment: thank you for asking, i save the User-custom-Properties in folder and it working fine , exception happen only 1st time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take benefit of the `AdvancedSearch` which works in background.

Precisely you can start an async search task using `Application.AdvancedSearch` (see [documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866933.aspx))

The `string scope` parameter is actually the Outlook folder where the search will be performed. I think you will probably use the default task folder (see [olDefaultFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.oldefaultfolders.aspx))

In your case, you will have to create a query with a CustomField. Here is the syntax (not tested). This weird `0x0000001f` is actually the internal id for `CustomProperties`, [see](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb147591(v=office.12).aspx)

```
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/TaskId/0x0000001f = 'yourid'"
```

Note that with `AdvancedSearch` you have the benefit to perform the search task in background and not freezing the UI thread. I recommend you to use an id to identify your search so you do not mess up with concurrent searches or cancellation.

Comment: thank you for reply and for helpful details, i appreciate your effort, i have another question if you can help me, ns.GetItemFromID throw exception if the item not exist, do you know anyway to avoid that , i used try and empty catch but i hate that way to handle errors

Comment: @mokhAkh considering the try/catch, I do not like it either but it seems that there is no alternative. I use also such a piece of code in my Outlook VSTO products

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it led me to a working solution.
If you are looking for a complete working filter, here is mine: `var filter = $"@SQL=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}}/MyUserProperty/0000001f\" = '{value}'";`